# docker container stops after docker run

Tags: docker, docker-container

I have a docker file which when built and run stops. I am trying to run both client and server in one docker container. If there is any solution to use docker-compose, then that is already in place and working fine. Please advise how to keep the container up and running using docker run. Thanks!

Here is my docker file, package.json and screenshot of folder structure.

DockerFile contents:

```
FROM node:14.14.0-alpine
RUN apk update && apk add bash
SHELL ["/bin/bash", "-o", "pipefail", "-c"]
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 3000
EXPOSE 4565
CMD ["npm","run","prebuild"]
```

docker build: command:

```
docker build -t sample .
```

docker run command:

```
docker run -d -it --name sm -v `pwd`:/app sample
```

Package.json:
[image]

Comment: What is the expected result? If you do 
`docker run -it -v $PWD:/app sh`

then do `npm run prebuild` 

what happens? 

does it start some long running program? Or does it do something and stop?

Whats happening is the main process of the container is finishing and then it has nothing to do so it kills the container...

Comment: I thought the CMD in dockerfile should trigger the command to keep the container up and running. However the commands in package.json were set to run in background, I made one of them to run in background and another in foreground which kept the container running.

Comment: A container only runs one process; it runs the `CMD`, and when the `CMD` exits the container exits too.  You should run the client and server as two separate containers and make sure they're run as foreground processes.